# Can a prime have arbitary many representations as a sum of two perfect powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $f(p)$ be the number of representations $$p=a+b$$ with perfect powers $0<a< b$

For example, $13$ has the only representation $$4+9=13$$ hence $f(13)=1$
$$41=9+32=16+25$$ has two representations, hence $f(41)=2$

The smallest primes that satisfy $$f(p)=1,2,3,4,5$$ are $$13,41,449,4481,93241$$ respective. I did not find this sequence in OEIS.

> Is $f(p)$ a bounded function ? If not, is $f(p)$ surjective on the natural numbers ?

Comment: I did not find a prime $p$ with $f(p)>5$ yet.

Comment: There might be something at http://oeis.org/A206606

Comment: An observation, if $p=a_1^m+b_1^n$ then $\gcd(n,m)=2^k$, $k$ may be $0$

Comment: 13, 41, 449, ... that's a sequence that might need to be in the OEIS. Have you tried searching for $f(2), f(3), f(5), f(7), \ldots$?

Comment: $f(4297609)=6$ , not sure whether this is the smallest example.

Comment: And $f(445\ 341\ 529)=7$. Also not sure whether it is the smallest.

Comment: that is amazing. How did you find them so quickly?

Comment: @user477343 My first approach was brute force - very slow! The next idea was to consider only the case $x^2+y^3=p$ (There is at most one solution of the form $x^2+y^2=p$ with $x<y$). This can be checked much faster. The third approach was to create a vector of the perfect powers and counting the sums, which after a refinement, allowed me to approve that the given examples are actually minimal solutions.

Comment: The smallest values for $8$ and $9$ representations are: $$f(4\:190\:216\:689)=8;$$ $$f(25\:140\:740\:257)=9.$$

Comment: @Oleg567 How did you find that out ? Or is it in OEIS ?

Comment: Like your $3$rd approach: for given range $[Min,Max]$ make array $a[]$ of the size $Max-Min$, filled by zeroes; create vector of the perfect powers (limited by $Max$), then consider their sums; for each such sum $s$ (if $Min\le s \le Max$) increase value $a[s-Min]$ ...

Comment: Wow, well done!

Comment: But I see now $2$ closely related OEIS links: https://oeis.org/A173795 and http://oeis.org/A162930 ( and http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_563.htm)...

Comment: In fact, it is (highly expected) coincidence that the smallest prime number that has $k$ representations as sum of $2$ perfect powers $-$ has $1$ representation of the form $a^2+b^2$ and $k-1$ representations of the form $a^2+b^3$.